# django cache - what does this do?

Tags: django, django-cache

I am reading django's cache framework and came across this code (not in the docs):

```
feed = cache.get('sfc:index:%s' % request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

I couldnot find this style of getting/settings caches by googling. what is the purpose of `:` inside cache key? what does this code exactly do with those three keys e.g. `sfc:index:en`?

sorry for the thumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is retrieving the cached data for a feed in the request language. The key, is only a key. :)

Comment: oh, so there is basically no difference between ``'index'`` and ``'index:bla'`` then right?

Comment: Without seeing the code could say that. But beware if this code is using or overriding something. Django offers a Cache key transformation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/cache/#cache-key-transformation) to combine the key prefix, key version and key to produce a final key. But this not match your 'sfc:index:%s' string.